# "No root file system is defined" when using kickstart

Tags: system-installation, kickstart

We are using Physical server and are in process of Automated “ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64” OS  installation on it.

There are two HDD for OS installation purpose and there are RAID1 relation between them. This setup has been done through BIOS.

The kickstart configuration file looks like this:

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone Asia/Dili
#Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$Yl1QJyta$KzIT.kq3i9E5XaiQKcUJn/
#Initial user
user ankit --fullname "Ankit" --iscrypted --password $1$c6Yflpea$pi1QQ59/jgywmGwBv25z3/
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use Web installation
url --url my_repo_location
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
#Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size 100 --ondisk sda
part / --fstype ext4 --size 10000 --ondisk sda
part /var --fstype ext4 --size 10000 --ondisk sda
part swap --size 1024 --ondisk sdb
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5
#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --enabled --trust=eth0 --http --ftp --ssh --telnet --smtp
#X Window System configuration information
xconfig --depth=8 --resolution=640x480 --defaultdesktop=GNOME
```

But I am getting the below error : `No root file system is defined`

Do we need to do any modification in kickstart configuration file?

The automated Ubuntu OS installation is successful in Virtual Machine(VM) with the above ks.cfg (kickstart configuration file ) but failing in case of physical machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kickstart uses /var/log/syslog for error reporting. You will see an error notice likely similar to this:

```
 ... kickseed: unsupported restriction 'ondisk' ...
```

As far as I know `--ondisk sda` was never supported by Ubuntu. Neither is partitioning more than 1 disc.

Remove it and it should work.

Kickstart is a Redhat utility that is also available on Ubuntu but our version lacks some features so it is best to keep an eye on /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Hi .. I am trying to install ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64” OS on a physical server and RAID1 relation has been established between two hard disk.Can you please provide the partitioning command to be included in kickstart file for automated installation. Thanks.